# I want to add onclick functionality on education-title div block, which hides/shows education-details div block in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, event-handling, onclicklistener

[code snippet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wo6gA.png)

B.Tech 73%
        
        
          Velagapudi RamaKrishna Siddhartha Engineering College
          Electronics and Communication Engineering
          2019-2023

i had tried in javascript using addevent listner, i want this in react... can any one say about accessing child element from container just like as dom manipulation in js?

Comment: Please post your code as text instead of an image.

Comment: [Here's some documentation on how to create a React snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/338538/1377002).

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.